# Shorten long branch names in Git

Tags: git

My shop has an obnoxiously long branch name convention:

`users/full.name/wi-1234-0`

Is there a way that I can type git commands without having to type this entire branch name hundreds of times? Something like `%branch%1234-0` where `branch` here is the `users/full.name/wi-` part. Where I can specify the work item number.

I prefer to use command line to UI because I have more control. I just don't want to keep typing these enormous branch names.

Comment: What OS? If on Linux (or Windows Terminal even), using tab after you've written some portion of the branch name for it to be definitely auto-completed, will complete it for you

Comment: I'm using Cmder on Windows.

Comment: Try tab after writing enough of the branch name for it to not conflict with any other branch names

Comment: Why do you need to type a branch name in a Git command? If it's the current branch, use `@`. If it's not, your shell will help you (if you've played your cards right).

Comment: Can I ask what I did wrong here? Why are people marking this question down? Did I ask it wrong?

Comment: @matt, I'm a little new to git. I've been using it for about 2 years. This is most annoying when I am working on more than one work item at a time. I did not know about `@`. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your own repo you can use whatever names you want. `git checkout -tb whatever origin/users/full.name/wi-1234-0`, that will set up the default pull, for pushing you'll need to `git config push.default upstream` because you're not a newbie any more.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks.